# JNI - create and return a `byte[][]` object

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a C implemented method that using JNI, should return a `byte[][]` type of result.

My code looks like:

```
jobjectArray result = java_env->NewObjectArray(num_byte_arrays, jbyteArray, NULL);
for (int i = 0 ; i < num_byte_arrays ; i++) {
    java_env->SetObjectArrayElement(result, i, java_env->NewByteArray(3));
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
   jobjectArray result = java_env->NewObjectArray(num_patches, jbyteArray, NULL);
                                                                         ^
```

I guess that my second parameter for `NewObjectArray`, that is `jbyteArray`, is incorrect for creating a `byte[][]` array.

Any idea how should I specify that the type of the object array is `byte[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it in the following way (kind of a workaround):

```
jobjectArray result = NULL;
for (int i = 0 ; i < num_byte_arrays ; i++) {
    jbyteArray byte_array = java_env->NewByteArray(3);
    if (i == 0) {
        result = java_env->NewObjectArray(num_byte_arrays, java_env->GetObjectClass(byte_array), NULL);
    }
    java_env->SetObjectArrayElement(result, i, byte_array);
}
```

What I did is, I created the object array only when the first `byte[]` object had already been ready. Running the JNI method `GetObjectClass` on the first `byte[]` object, I could specify for `NewObjectArray` the `jobject` parameter it wanted.

Not sure what other way can give you a `jobject` item that represents `byte[]`.

Comment: It might also work with `jclass byte_array_class = env->FindClass("[B")`, rather than using `GetObjectClass` on the first object.